# React child component only updates on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-functional-component

I am using function components in React and I have a parent component called *'Challenges'* and a child component called *'ChallengeItem'*.

The *'Challenges'* component calls an action called *'getAllChallenges'* which gets all the challenges from my database and maps through them:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAllChallenges } from '../../actions/challenge';
import Loading from '../layout/Loading';
import ChallengeItem from './ChallengeItem';

const Challenges = ({
  getAllChallenges,
  challenge: { challenges, loading },
  progress,
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllChallenges();
  }, [getAllChallenges]);

  return loading ? (
    <Loading />
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className='text-center mt-5'>Course Syllabus</h1>
      <div className='row mt-5 mx-5 row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-4 g-4'>
        {challenges.map((challenge) => (
          <ChallengeItem key={challenge._id} challenge={challenge} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Challenges.propTypes = {
  getAllChallenges: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  challenge: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  progress: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  challenge: state.challenge,
  progress: state.auth.user.progress,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllChallenges })(Challenges);
```

The *'ChallengeItem'* component returns a Fragment that displays individual challenge information dynamically:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ChallengeItem = ({
  auth,
  user: { progress },
  challenge: { _id, section_name, section_no, challenge_no, challenge_name },
}) => (
  <Fragment>
    <div className='col'>
      <div className='card challengeCard'>
        <div className='card-body'>
          <h5 className='card-title'>
            Section {section_no}, Challenge {challenge_no}
          </h5>
          <p className='card-text'>
            {section_name}- {challenge_name}
          </p>
          {isChallengeUnlocked(_id, progress) ? (
            <Link
              to={`/challenge/${_id}`}
              className='btn btn-secondary pinkBtn'
            >
              Unlocked <i className='fas fa-lock-open'></i>
            </Link>
          ) : (
            <button className='btn btn-secondary pinkBtn' disabled>
              Locked <i className='fas fa-lock'></i>
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
);

ChallengeItem.propTypes = {
  challenge: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  user: state.auth.user,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChallengeItem);

function isChallengeUnlocked(_id, progress) {
  for (const value of progress) {
    if (value.challenge === _id) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Also in the *'ChallengeItem'* component is a function which determines based on the users progress, whether they have unlocked a particular challenge.

If they have unlocked a challenge it will be displayed and the user will be able to click on the link to navigate to that challenge.

If they have **not** unlocked a challenge it will be displayed but the button will be *disabled* for this challenge and the user will be unable to click it.

The issue I am having is that when a challenge is newly unlocked by the user and the user then navigates to the Challenges page to view all the locked/unlocked challenges, the newly unlocked challenge is displaying on the page as locked and only when the page is refreshed will the newly unlocked challenge appear unlocked.

How can I get the challenges to re-render when the child component updates?

I searched for an answer online and it seems a lot are saying about having a key for the child component in order for it to re-render but I am already doing this. I'm not sure what the problem is, maybe it's a separate issue.

I would really appreciate any help at this stage, thank you!

EDIT:

```
// getAllChallenges action
export const getAllChallenges = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/challenge/all`);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_CHALLENGES,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: CHALLENGE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};
```

```
// UPDATE_PROGRESS reducer
case UPDATE_PROGRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {
          ...state.user,
          progress: payload,
        },
        loading: false,
      };
```

Comment: Currently, you only fetch at the beginning. You need to pass the progress to the function, then add it to the dependency array. Basically, if the progress changes trigger the fetch.

Comment: I have tried changing useEffect in the Challenge component to:  

useEffect(() => {
    getAllChallenges();
  }, [progress]);

to attempt to load all challenges when the progress state changes but it is still giving me the same problem

Comment: How does the `getAllChallenges` action look like?

Comment: Hi Seshkebab, I deleted my answer, sorry for that. I missed that you were using redux. By the way, can you not dispatch an action when you find out that the challenge has got unlocked. This will update the `challenges` stored in the redux store?

Comment: @merko I have updated my answer with the getAllChallenges action attached

Comment: @JayendraSharan No worries, I do dispatch an action when the challenge gets unlocked, it's called UPDATE_PROGRESS. This adds the current challenge to the users progress array.

Comment: @JayendraSharan Sorry if it seems a bit confusing, but I call getAllChallenges to display all the challenges on that page and then I use the function isChallengeUnlocked (located at the bottom of the ChallengeItem component), this takes in the challenge id and the users progress array as arguments, it then loops through the users progress array and if the id in the progress array matches the id of a challenge displayed on the page then it displays this challenge as unlocked, otherwise it will be locked and the button disabled

Comment: Okay. Could you show the reducer for `UPDATE_PROGRESS` action?

Comment: @JayendraSharan I've added this under edits in the main question

Comment: So you say, progress is an array? Right. The what do you mean by this line `progress: payload,`? Shouldn't you be doing something like `progress: [...state.user.progress, payload]` or `progress: [...state.user.progress, ...payload]` if payload is an array.

Comment: It makes no difference whether it is ```progress: payload``` or ```progress [...state.user.progress, payload]``` the challenge **is** being appended onto the users progress either way. That isn't addressing the issue, the issue is that the newly unlocked challenge is appearing visibly disabled as though it is still locked, then on page refresh it updates to represent this new challenge now being unlocked. So I would like to point out that the user progress IS updating as expected it is the React component that is not.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ChallengeItem` is a Redux connected component that doesn't *only* rely on the Redux state, you'll need to set [`pure: false` in the `connect()` options](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#options-object):

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {pure: false})(ChallengeItem);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it did not work for me